# Matching pattern containing parentheses with sed

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I need to insert '--' at the beginning of the line if line contains word VARCHAR(1000)

Sample of my file is:

> TRIM(CAST("AP_RQ_MSG_TYPE_ID" AS NVARCHAR(1000))) AP_RQ_MSG_TYPE_ID,
>   TRIM(CAST("AP_RQ_PROCESSING_CD" AS NVARCHAR(1000)))
>   AP_RQ_PROCESSING_CD, TRIM(CAST("AP_RQ_ACQ_INST_ID" AS NVARCHAR(11)))
>   AP_RQ_ACQ_INST_ID, TRIM(CAST("AP_RQ_LOCAL_TXN_TIME" AS NVARCHAR(10)))
>   AP_RQ_LOCAL_TXN_TIME, TRIM(CAST("AP_RQ_LOCAL_TXN_DATE" AS
>   NVARCHAR(10))) AP_RQ_LOCAL_TXN_DATE, TRIM(CAST("AP_RQ_RETAILER" AS
>   NVARCHAR(11))) AP_RQ_RETAILER,

I used this command

```
sed 's/\(^.*VARCHAR\(1000\).*$\)/--\1/I' *.sql
```

But the result is not as expected.
Does anyone have idea what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

this should do:

```
sed 's/.*VARCHAR(1000).*/--&/' file
```

The problem in your sed command is at the regex part. By default sed uses BRE, which means, the `( and )` (wrapping the `1000`) are just literal brackets, you should **not** escape them, or you gave them special meaning: regex grouping.

The first and last `(..)` you have escaped, there  you did right, if you want to reference it later by `\1`. so your problem is escape or not escape. :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the following sed command:

```
sed '/VARCHAR(1000)/ s/.*/--\0/' *.sql
```

The `s` command appplies to all lines containing `VARCHAR(1000)`. It then replaces the whole line `.*` by itself `\0` with `--` in front.

Comment: awk way `awk '/VARCHAR(1000)/ {print "--"$0}' *.sql`

Comment: While it will work with awk too, I don't think this is an awk task. It's a typical task one would manually do in a text editor, and for those is sed. That's how I decide between using sed or awk.

Comment: I was showing a similar(practically identical) way in awk. Not necessarily saying it is better. Just thought id provide more information and let them choose which they like :) I personally prefer to use awk over sed as i find it more readable.

Comment: @Jidder your awk command won't work. since you have to escape the `( and )`, something like `awk '$1=/VARCHAR\(1000\)/?"--"$1:$1' file` . and I am with hek2mgl, this is not an awk task, even tough awk can do it too.

Comment: I understand the backslashes, but why have you added all the `$1`'s and `/?` .It works fine with the backslashes but otherwise exactly the same ? Also i was just providing an alternative which is why i didnt post it as a real answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Through awk,

```
awk '/VARCHAR\(1000\)/ {sub (/^/,"--")}1' infile > outfile
```